# Why is my header border and font showing up weird?

Tags: html, css

*Disclaimer: I know that I should be using a sprite for my nav, I just couldn't get it to work with my images. Yes I know what I have now is a bad substitute. Please don't judge the current state of my site as it is in a very early stage and I am quite new to coding.*

Please look at my code and tell me why

1. there is a white border around my header
2. the font is not showing up as it's supposed to.

Thank you so much!

Website: http://www.philecialabounty.com/KVS2/index.html

Roboto-Thin Font is supposed to look like: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto

Comment: done any debugging yourself, e.g. use a dom inspector to look at the element with the border?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not clicking on a random link from an unknown website. Could you provide more details, or replicate the problem on a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: What do you mean your font isn't loading up? Works fine for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: @freefaller website seems legit TBF.

Comment: @freefaller would anyone really take the time to come HERE to link you to a malicious site? Come on

Comment: @VerucaSalt You would be surprised what comes by here very day.. I do have to make one remark on your site: do **not** use the `<center>` tag. Want to center your divs? Use `margin: <something> auto;`!!

Comment: As you seem to be new to this, one of the most important tools for front end development is your browsers "Developers tools"  I use firebug which is a plugin for firefox but all browsers have them...learn to use them, it will be invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the border, your body is using the browser's default margin + padding for the body.  Look into a CSS reset file. Or take a look at boilerplate or just assign body a margin/padding of 0.

In regards to the font not showing up properly, can you only use web-safe fonts in the font family declaritive for css.  If you want to use better fonts look up Google fonts or cufon (which I usually use)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have the body margin/padding set to 0 already - Can you provide further details on how I might fix this?

Comment: @VerucaSalt no you don't

Answer (score 0):

As @hendr1x suggests, the reason for the padding/margin is that every browser has it's own *default* stylesheet which it uses for some very basic base properties. If you were to check out the stylesheets used by various websites, you'd often bump into something named `reset.css`, which is just a simple stylesheet to ensure that basic styling is consistent across browsers, due to the issue above. Therefore, if you're only styling issue is the padding/margin on the body set by many browsers, just add:

```
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

At the top of your `stylesheet.css`. Alternatively, you could Google for a reset.css file, which would also do the job and more.

It's a little unclear what you mean as to "the font is not showing up properly" - I'll take that to mean that it's rendering poorly (i.e. it looks uncrisp/jaggedy/poor). If you're a Windows Chrome user, then, like many, you've just bumped into how poor it's font rendering can be. Bearing in mind that Chrome's market share is so high, perhaps you should reconsider your choice of font, and find one that's Chrome friendly. As a Firefox user, I find few/no issues with font rendering in Gecko, but I do often find problems with Legacy IE and Chrome. [Google Web-Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/) is a great resource for web-safe fonts, though even then I'd note that [Chrome issues are still rife](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137692).

**Also**: Why do you have a `<center>` tag? It doesn't seem to be doing anything and it's not in the HTML5 spec - I'd advise you remove it.